# What are the issues of look-up table based implementations?

Tags: block-cipher

Cryptographic libraries mostly use pre-computed lookup tables to implement block ciphers. These lookup tables require large amout of memory and a series of cache miss/hit makes them vulnerable to cache timing attacks.
Are there any other disadvantages of lookup table based implementations?

Comment: Why do we need more disadvantages than that? If the table lookups are still used, shouldn't you be looking for *advantages* instead? Are large memory requirements really such a big deal for a software implementation? It needs to be a rather large table before it doesn't fit in my 1st level cache anymore to start with. I see a lot of presumptions here, and a rather strange introduction for the question itself.

Comment: You can countermeasure the cache attack very easily. Just access all the keys regardless of usage.

Comment: @kelalaka, any rough estimate about the overhead of the suggested method?

Comment: AFAIK, OpenSLL uses this method. Maybe you can find some numbers over there.

Comment: @khan  you could do a bit-sliced implementation, but what a pain.  Alternatively, if you are superuser, you could either lock the cache or disable it for an address range in the MMU.  http://www.moserware.com/2008/09/how-do-locks-lock.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The disadvantages are simply the side-channel attacks that you mention.  I can think of no other disadvantages from either a cryptographic or hardware angle.    I have a description of [cache and attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/53528/why-dont-table-lookups-run-in-constant-time/53627#53627) from a hardware perspective.

The advantages are pretty clear:

1. simplicity in implementation so that the mathematics is correct;
2. it's faster than a bit-slice implementation, and
3. it's smaller than doing the inverse mathematics for the irreducible polynomial.

Also, in non-x86 environments, these attacks are be mitigated through a cache lock where you do not flush the cache so you cannot miss.

Comment: One possible disadvantage is a higher cache pressure for large lookup tables.

Comment: @forest good point.  I'm not sure the largest lookup table used in a cryptographic algorithm.

Comment: Many optimized implementations use a _lot_ of lookup tables. AES has quite a few (far more than just a single 8-bit S-box). It can certainly put pressure on the L1d cache.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two disadvantages:

- One issue of look-up tables (such as T-implementation of AES)  is when you target low memory environment.
- Software masking of look-up tables to protect against side channel requires addition of  extra memory ([An Efficient Masking Scheme for AES Software Implementations](https://www.emsec.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/media/crypto/veroeffentlichungen/2011/01/29/sw_masking.ps) ).